# Apply custom colors for new vector layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, color, vector-layer

I am trying to have a custom color palette applied when new vector layers are added. This is for use within a default project or template. But every time I load a vector layer, it chooses from the "new layer colors" palette which I don't want.

I have tried replacing the colors within the palette and saving it, as well as importing a palette, but it didn't save within the dialog box. I went through all the settings but didn't find anything.

I have also tried removing the "new Layer colors" palette altogether but nothing happens, even though the manual says "By default, Recent colors, Standard colors and Project colors palettes can not be removed and are set to appear in the color button drop-down."

Any idea how to replace or remove the "new layer colors" palette, or maybe another method I could use to have new vector layers to automatically have custom colors?

The issue is the same in versions 3.14, 3.18 and 3.20

[image: new layer colors - muted palette]

Comment: Did you try deleting all colors and then adding `New ramp` with the three dots `...` at the upper right?

Comment: Do you mean "New Palette"? Yes I have... after closing and reopening the settings window to check, it reverts back to the default new layer colors.

Comment: Would categories work for this?